# pca9685 and node mcu using micropython

Tags: i2c, nodemcu, micropython

I have a Lolin MCU like this [Lolin v3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwifhoO0pbnhAhUwx4UKHWktDI4QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instructables.com%2Fid%2FGetting-Started-With-ESP8266LiLon-NodeMCU-V3Flashi%2F&psig=AOvVaw3y60fO6X7LMELdpawLK1nT&ust=1554565361554775)

I have a PCA9685 board like this [cheap controller](https://www.makerlab-electronics.com/my_uploads/2015/05/PCA9685-16ch-12bit-PWM-Driver.jpg)

And Im coding in microPython in the nodeMCU device. I managed to attach one of those small 9g servos to the nodeMCU board and controll it. No problem. I want to use a controller since I need more servos, so I connect the PCA like this:

```
PCA V+  <--> 3v3 in the mcu (5v produce no changes)
PCA GND <--> GND in the mcu
PCA SDA <--> SDA (Pin 4) in the mcu
PCA SCL <--> SCL (Pin 5) in the mcu
PCA OE  <--> GND, V+ or open. Makes no difference
```

Now I downloaded this PCA9685.py and Servo.py from this web [microPython PCA controller](https://bitbucket.org/thesheep/micropython-pca9685/src)

I create an I2C like this

```
>>> i2c = machine.I2C(scl=machine.Pin(5), sda=machine.Pin(4))
>>> i2c.scan()
[64, 112]
```

So the device is there. The cables are good, the i2c is working. But the servos won't move no matter what. Not even buzz.

I try moving the servo using

```
servos.position(1, us=1500)
```

no thing happened.. I connected several servos in several ports to make sure is port 1 not port 0 and those stupid errors.. nothing.

This is the code I'm running at the device right now:

```
from machine import I2C, Pin
import servo

servos = servo.Servos(I2C(scl=Pin(5), sda=Pin(4))
for i in range(16):
    servos.position(i, us=1500)
```

Any clue ???

Comment: Show the code where you create `servos`. Have you done any electrical testing to make sure the PCA9685 board actually works?

Comment: you can find the code in the link, it is not mine  https://bitbucket.org/thesheep/micropython-pca9685/src As for the hardware, it works when connected to my Pi

Comment: None of the code files at that link creates an object called `servos`. Show us exactly what you do, if you want help.

Comment: added the code to the question, hope it brings some light :)

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong there. What code do you use on the Pi? I'm still thinking we haven't ruled out an electrical issue - is the power supply to the servo definitely OK? Have you tried just using the `PCA9685` class with no servo connected and checking the output with an oscilloscope? Failing all that I'd suggest asking on the MicroPython forum where there appears to be some knowledge in this area e.g. https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=4467&hilit=pca9685